# React Router V6 shows blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am facing a problem. I am trying to use React Router but it keeps showing me a blank page.
Here is my code:

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "./HomePage";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>

  );
};

export default App;
```

HomePage.js:

```
import React from "react";
import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom"

const HomePage = () => {

    return <div>hi</div>
}

export default HomePage;
```

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import App from './App';


ReactDom.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

I've installed "React Router V6", can anyone tell me what is the problem?
Thanks for all the helpers.

Comment: its working fine here

Comment: I think you should remove import of withRouter from HomePage component and then try otherwise, you need to share screenshot of error.

Comment: check the browser console for errors. usually if there is a "blank page" it means there was some type of exception thrown and it should show up in the console.

Comment: I see no overt issues in the code and suspect it would render without issue if I copy/pasted it into a codesandbox.

Answer (score 5):

use

```
import { Route, HashRouter as Router, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

 <Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route exact path="/" element={<Main />} />
    <Route path="/download" element={<Download />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded the react-router-dom package version to ^5... And it worked for me.

Note: Routes is not a method of this version

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue happen to me a couple of times. My code is exactly similar to yours. Open the `package.json` file in your project folder and make sure you've installed `react-router-dom` in the actual project folder and not in its parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened with me last night, possibly you have not installed `react-router-dom` in your project folder, try:

`cd [Project Folder name]`

`npm i react-router-dom`

This works for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I was using a (Create React App) CRA generated application and there were older dependencies and one of them was `react-router-dom`. If that's the case you might need to update your dependencies

`npm update`

or

`yarn upgrade`

These commands will update the packages in your project to the latest versions that satisfy the specified version range in your package.json file.

But you can update `react-router-dom` specifically like so

// Using npm

```
npm update react-router react-router-dom
```

or

// Using Yarn

```
yarn upgrade react-router react-router-dom
```

Let me know what works cause this gave me a headache too.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Routes,Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from 'components/Login';
import Headerfrom 'components/Header';
    
function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Header />
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path='/' element={<Login />} />
          </Routes>
       
       
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

> Above codes are for App.js file then in index.js it have to look like this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this problem today. After some investigation, I found out that I was install react-router-dom in the parent folder of my ReactJS project.

Something like this "C:\parent_foleder\reactjs_app", you can turn on terminal app, cd into parent_folder, and then **ls -a** to see if there is any node_moudles, package.json and package-json.lock; if those things existing in parent_folder, just delete them, then cd into your reactjs_app and run **npm i react-router-dom** again.

Answer (score -1):

you have done a silly mistake.
1 go to package to  json is there react-route-dom
2-if not install it in your project folder. you may have created a folder on desktop like npx create-react-app router and after that you had had installed the react-router-dom. just go cd yourprojectname and install.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).